# Codeigniter Redirect/Load view

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I really want to understand whats the best use of both functions.

Controller: (After much processing, lets skip directly to creating the session)

```
$isLoggedin = array( 'user_name' => $row['username'] , 'user_type' => 'user' ,  'is_loggedin' => TRUE);
$this->session->set_user($isLoggedin); 
redirect('controller/index');
```

in the controller,

```
public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
    //should i check for the session here?
}

function index(){
 // or should i check here?
}
```

In the login controller, after creating the  session, i passed it to the main controller, Before accessing the homepage, i want to verify if the `session['is_loggedin'] == TRUE` that signifies the session that was created = logged in.

My confusion is, since the constructor function is loaded first right everytime you call the controller. Please correct me if im wrong.  So in the redirect in the log in controller, i shouldnt call the index?

should i just call the controller there then let the constructor handle, then in the constructor, like this.

```
public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
if($session['is_loggedin'] == TRUE)
$this->load->view('homepage');
else
redirect('Login');
}
```

So i guess i wont need the index anymore right? Is it okay to call the controller that way? in the redirect, also do i have to pass the $session from controller to controller?

Comment: In codeigniter the use of constructor is mainly to load common libraries and helpers which can be used in the other functions of your class. Index function works as a default function when there is no particular function is mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better check for the user if he has a logged in session in your constructor function before loading any libraries or helpers. but make sure session and database are loaded to check users login status. this can help you to prevent any other unauthorized access to the other functions and resources of your website, cause one might just type the name of some other functions into the URL directly!

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor to load common libraries and helpers which are needed for the other functions in that particular class.
Index function works as a default function when there is no other function is mentioned.
For example you can do like this

```
public function index(){
  $this->login();
}

public function login(){
  login code

}
```

so this way `your base url/class name/` and `base url/class name/ login` both will work.
If you autoload session library in your `application/config/autoload.php` file you don't need to worry about session, just you need to set an encryption key in `config.php` file

If you don't want to autoload session then you need to load session manually on every class's constructor where you need to maintain session.

Comment: I have already loaded every single library and helpers i need in my config. So does that mean construct function is now obsolete?

anyhow, what about the redirect and load view. I want to maximize my usage. I want to develop websites with decent codes. Can you explain to me the difference in uses.

Comment: autoload is like a super common task holder, constructor is like common task holder for a specific class. You should not autoload everything unless you need every library and helper in all functions of all your controllers.

Comment: are you trying to not show login page if users are already logged in? and if users try to access login page via url you want to redirect back to home page?

Comment: Just a simple log in with session, wherein if the user is logged in it should validate first if the session was created. Plus i have my confusions, if i set the $session, i won't need to pass it from controller to controller righT? say, if i have a controller for logging in and i set the $session data there, if i access that $session data in other controller to see if it exists. 

OH and yeah, how do i do about thaT? what if the user uses the back button on the browser? should i add a php function in the log in page(view) to check if already logged in?